# Custom render feature local

Tags: unity, c#

Is custom render feature suppose to be global? As in the values set through it affects all materials that share a common name? I am looking to set a value for each of my materials and unfortunately this does not work.

For example: https://github.com/tomc128/urp_kawase_blur

This repo consists of a custom render feature that blurs a material that shares the name "_blurTexture". The `blurPasses` and `downsample` are defined as global. Is there a way that these can be defined as local so that each material has its own blurPasses and downsample. If so, what and how to achieve this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

public class KawaseBlur : ScriptableRendererFeature
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class KawaseBlurSettings
    {
        public RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent = RenderPassEvent.AfterRenderingTransparents;
        public Material blurMaterial = null;

        [Range(2,15)]
        public int blurPasses = 1;

        [Range(1,4)]
        public int downsample = 1;
        public bool copyToFramebuffer;
        public string targetName;
        public string NameOfRenderPass;
    }

    public KawaseBlurSettings settings = new KawaseBlurSettings();

    class CustomRenderPass : ScriptableRenderPass
    {
        public Material blurMaterial;
        public int passes;
        public int downsample;
        public bool copyToFramebuffer;
        public string targetName;    
        public string NameOfRenderPass;    
        string profilerTag;

        int tmpId1;
        int tmpId2;

        RenderTargetIdentifier tmpRT1;
        RenderTargetIdentifier tmpRT2;
        
        private RenderTargetIdentifier source { get; set; }

        public void Setup(RenderTargetIdentifier source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        public CustomRenderPass(string profilerTag)
        {
            this.profilerTag = profilerTag;
        }

        public override void Configure(CommandBuffer cmd, RenderTextureDescriptor cameraTextureDescriptor)
        {
            var width = cameraTextureDescriptor.width / downsample;
            var height = cameraTextureDescriptor.height / downsample;

            tmpId1 = Shader.PropertyToID("tmpBlurRT1");
            tmpId2 = Shader.PropertyToID("tmpBlurRT2");
            cmd.GetTemporaryRT(tmpId1, width, height, 0, FilterMode.Bilinear, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
            cmd.GetTemporaryRT(tmpId2, width, height, 0, FilterMode.Bilinear, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

            tmpRT1 = new RenderTargetIdentifier(tmpId1);
            tmpRT2 = new RenderTargetIdentifier(tmpId2);
            
            ConfigureTarget(tmpRT1);
            ConfigureTarget(tmpRT2);
        }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get(profilerTag);

            RenderTextureDescriptor opaqueDesc = renderingData.cameraData.cameraTargetDescriptor;
            opaqueDesc.depthBufferBits = 0;

            // first pass
            // cmd.GetTemporaryRT(tmpId1, opaqueDesc, FilterMode.Bilinear);
            cmd.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 1.5f);
            cmd.Blit(source, tmpRT1, blurMaterial);

            for (var i=1; i<passes-1; i++) {
                cmd.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 0.5f + i);
                cmd.Blit(tmpRT1, tmpRT2, blurMaterial);

                // pingpong
                var rttmp = tmpRT1;
                tmpRT1 = tmpRT2;
                tmpRT2 = rttmp;
            }

            // final pass
            cmd.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 0.5f + passes - 1f);
            if (copyToFramebuffer) {
                cmd.Blit(tmpRT1, source, blurMaterial);
            } else {
                cmd.Blit(tmpRT1, tmpRT2, blurMaterial);
                cmd.SetGlobalTexture(targetName, tmpRT2);
            }

            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            cmd.Clear();

            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }

        public override void FrameCleanup(CommandBuffer cmd)
        {
        }
    }

    CustomRenderPass scriptablePass;

    public override void Create()
    {
        
        scriptablePass = new CustomRenderPass(settings.NameOfRenderPass);
        scriptablePass.blurMaterial = settings.blurMaterial;
        scriptablePass.passes = settings.blurPasses;
        scriptablePass.downsample = settings.downsample;
        scriptablePass.copyToFramebuffer = settings.copyToFramebuffer;
        scriptablePass.targetName = settings.targetName;

        scriptablePass.renderPassEvent = settings.renderPassEvent;
    }

    public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        var src = renderer.cameraColorTarget;
        scriptablePass.Setup(src);
        renderer.EnqueuePass(scriptablePass);
    }
}
```

[image: RenderFeature]

Comment: This does not look to me like it targets a specific material sharing the name _blurTexture as you describe. It's a post:process effect that blurs everything in the frame buffer at the time the pass runs. If you want to blur a single material within your scene, you should ask how to do that. A render feature might not be the right way to accomplish that effect, depending on what you have in mind. You should also show an example of the effect you want — usually blurring something means blending its pixels with nearby pixels, so it's unclear how that works if only one material is to be blurred.

Comment: This does *output* the *result* of the blur into a texture called `_blurTexture`. If that's the behaviour you want though, it seems like you could simply add multiple instances of this effect, with different parameters and output textures configured.

Comment: @DMGregory you are right. Render feature is not the right way to blur multiple materials. I am looking for a frost glass effect in URP. I am able to achieve it with the above library, is there an alternate solution?

Comment: Are you unsatisfied with the result you're getting currently? Asking "How to improve my frosted glass effect", showing what your effect looks like currently, and what you want to change about it, would be a better way to get to solutions that work for that use case.

Comment: Well the library is perfect. Problem is that I want to set different blur passes for each material, which is not the case since it is declared as global. I am finding difficulty in converting the above script to monobehavior so that I can set blur passes for each material separately.

Comment: "If that's the behaviour you want though, it seems like you could simply add multiple instances of this effect, with different parameters and output textures configured." - what is preventing you from achieving the look you want with the existing library, just applying multiple copies of the renderer feature writing to different textures?

Comment: Well i tried multiple instances but when I change the blur passes, it affects all its instances. :( which is why i am really stressing on the term "global".

Comment: Then I will tell you again that you should edit your question to demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve, [not the non-working solution you've thought of so far](http://xyproblem.info/).